# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type in C code

Tags: c

I called the below function passing a struct pointer. I'm getting the error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" where ever I pointed currentTableItem -> Please help.

Comment: Where is `currentTableItem` declared?

Comment: Where's the definition of that structure?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the full declaration of `struct md_CamsLatchTblStruct` is not known to the compiler at this time, probably because you used a forward declaration:

the compiler sees:

```
struct md_CamsLatchTblStruct;
```

The compiler doesn't see (not included / defined in another source file):

```
struct md_CamsLatchTblStruct {
     int index;
     int addr;
     int mask;
     int startBit;
     // ..
};
```

Comment: I have 2 structs... like this.. I'm passing LatchTbl through a pointer to the function int read(struct TblStruct *defaultTable)
as shown above                                                struct TblStruct {
 int index;
 int16_t data;
 int addr;
 int startBit;
 int16_t mask;
};                                                                                                                                           struct TblStruct LatchTbl[]={
{0   00,    0,  0,  0xFF,    0},
{1   00,    1,  0,  0xFF,    1},
{2   00,    2,  0,  0xFF,    2}};

Comment: I didn't say you didn't declare it. I said the declaration is not visible at the time of compiling the code you showed. Where is this declaration appears?